# How to update Urls of WP Layer Slider, while moving site from old domain to new domain

Tags: wordpress

I have tried "Go Live", "Better Search Replace" & "Velvet Blues Update URLs" Plugins to update urls. They updated the data for all tables except "wp_layerslider". I researched on it couple of blogs are saying just uninstall and reinstall "LayerSlider WP" plugin & re-enter data. That is not logical. Please suggest some technical solution, because that will be faster than data-entry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you can replace url in LayerSlider WP very simple:

```
UPDATE  `wp_layerslider` SET  `data` = REPLACE(  `data` ,  'http:\\/\\/old-website.com\\/',  'http:\\/\\/new-website.com\\/' )
```

Comment: Your sql command doesn't working

Answer (score 0):

backup sql of old domain to import it to phpmyadmin of new domain. and then go to **Setting** >> **Permalink** >> **Save changes**